# Rogue Zone in my Irrigation System

Tags: irrigation, repair

I've recently run into an issue with my irrigation system where one of the zones is "stuck". When I have the control panel set to "system off" this zone pops up and seems to run endlessly. I have to shut off water to the system to make it stop running.

I notice that if I start with water off to the system, start the desired program, and turn the water on, then all zones runs as expected (however, after the final programmed zone is complete the rogue zone pops back up). If the rogue zone is already running and I start a program, the rogue zone stays up, so 2 zones are running at once, the rogue zone and programmed zone.

I had a repair company come through last week and they indicated they think the control panel is bad. However, it'll now be 2 weeks before they can come back out and the peculiar behavior has me second guessing. Anybody run into something similar before?

Comment: It is most definitely your control panel because there's nothing else that it could be. The analog system obviously works or else the "rouge zone" wouldn't turn on at all or would it would have some other sign of physical failure. Turning on or off sporadically is a telltale sign of digital control problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, if there is a flow control on the top of the valve, turn it
>   down till the zone stops running. If there isn't a flow control the
>   valve might need to be cleaned. In any case clean it. Second,
>   disconnect one of the wires and see if the valve shuts off.  If it
>   doesn't it's the valve or the solenoid. Easy fix.  Controller is last
>   resort.

I ran your question by my old boss; Landscape Design and Landscape Construction...Stephen Schneider.  Made sense to me, let me know if this works for you!  Thanks Steve!